# Microsoft Azure HDInsight -"Not Valid JAR"

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I have got the following prompt (see attachment below) when I run an example from the Implementing Big Data Analysis course.
"Not a Valid JAR"

The command:

C:\apps\dist\hadoop-2.6.0.2.2.7.1-0004>hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar wordcount /example/data/gutenberg/davici.txt /example/results

Please advise how to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The examples file was renamed when YARN was added in Hadoop 2.x, HDInsight 3.x.  If you do a `dir` listing at the command prompt, you will see that it's now called `hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar`, so the following command should work

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount /example/data/gutenberg/davinci.txt /example/results
```

*(you also had a typo in davi**n**ci.txt)*